# process crash on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I try to getting start with Rails 3.0.11 and Heroku. My Ruby version is 1.9.2 and my file database.yml is like this:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: bhasezmsgs
  pool: 5
  username: xxxxxx
  password: xxxxxx
```

This informations database, username and password is from

```
  heroku console  
  ENV['DATABASE_URL']
```

I have on production.rb, on development.rb and on test.rb this:

```
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
```

when write on terminal foreman start I take this

```
 started with pid 3369
 You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for your /      environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :log, :notify or :stderr at config/environments//.rb
```

and when write heroku logs I take this

```
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:8:in   `size': No such file or directory - log/production/production.log (Errno::ENOENT)
```

but I have ruby 1.9.2 and I can't find this file /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/...

Finaly I use Ubuntu and my Gemfile is

```
  source 'http://rubygems.org'
  gem 'rails', '3.0.11'
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
```

Comment: don't post real usernames and passwords

Comment: what does your foreman Procfile look like, I don't think you are starting thin correctly? `:stderr at config/environments//.rb` note that should be config/environments/production.rb but is blank?

Answer (score 1):

try using this in your Procfile

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
```

Comment: my Procfile is on root directrory of my app and look like this          web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV/$RAILS_ENV

Comment: Thanks this Procfile is best for my app process. When delete my $RAILS_ENV my app works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In production.rb try:

```
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
```

In development.rb try:

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

In test.rb try:

```
config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
```

Also make sure that you in your database.yml file that your 3 environments are the same (i.e. all Postgres). It will make it easier with Heroku hosting in the future.

If that doesn't work, copy the error messages and we'll see where we can go from there.

Comment: The error on heroku logs is the same :/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:8:in `size': No such file or directory - log/production/production.log (Errno::ENOENT)           
also heroku[router] say Error H10 (App crashed) There somewhere a file log_tailer.rb and I do not know where is stored.